# Specifying a proportion in a nested table in prop.table

Tags: r, contingency

I make a four way table with `xtabs`

```
library(magrittr)
xtabs( ~ vs + gear + cyl, data = mtcars) %>% 
  ftable(row.vars = "gear")
```

returns

```
     vs   0        1      
     cyl  4  6  8  4  6  8
gear                      
3         0  0 12  1  2  0
4         0  2  0  8  2  0
5         1  1  2  1  0  0
```

Now I want proportions *within* levels of `mtcars$vs`.

If I use `prop.table`

```
xtabs( ~ vs + gear + cyl, data = mtcars) %>% 
  ftable(row.vars = "gear") %>% 
  prop.table(margin = 1) %>% 
  round(2)
```

I get

```
     vs     0              1          
     cyl    4    6    8    4    6    8
gear                                  
3        0.00 0.00 0.80 0.07 0.13 0.00
4        0.00 0.17 0.00 0.67 0.17 0.00
5        0.20 0.20 0.40 0.20 0.00 0.00
```

Ie--I want the entry for vs == 0, gear == 3, cyl == 8, to be 1.00

Comment: Why 1? Do you want the cumulative proportion?In your original table that entry is 0. How is that going to translate to 1?

Comment: No, I want proportions within levels of `vs`. 

I read the entry in the original table of vs == 0, gear == 3, cyl == 8 as having a count of 12, no?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 xtabs( ~ vs + gear + cyl, data = mtcars) %>% 
   ftable(row.vars = c("gear","vs")) %>% 
   prop.table(margin = 1) %>% 
   round(2)
```

the results are

```
        cyl    4    6    8
gear vs                   
3    0      0.00 0.00 1.00
     1      0.33 0.67 0.00
4    0      0.00 1.00 0.00
     1      0.80 0.20 0.00
5    0      0.25 0.25 0.50
     1      1.00 0.00 0.00
```